# How to use C++ operator[] in Cython?

Tags: c++, python, cython

I need to wrap a C++ class FooContainer defining the operator[]:

```
//foo.h:
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
  Foo()
    : value(42) {};
  int value;   
};


class FooContainer
{
public:
    FooContainer() { this->values = vector<Foo> (100) ;}
    Foo operator[](int i) {return values[i];}; // <-- the function I need to call

private:
  vector<Foo> values;    

};
```

I'm trying to write the corresponding .pyx file but whatever I try I can't figure out how to use Foo::operator

```
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref


cdef extern from "foo.h":
   cdef cppclass CppFoo "Foo":
     pass

cdef extern from "foo.h":
   cdef cppclass CppFooContainer "FooContainer":
     FooContainer()
     Foo operator[](int)


cdef class Foo:
    cdef CppFoo * thisptr

cdef class FooContainer:
    cdef CppFooContainer* thisptr

    def __cinit__(self):
       self.thisptr = new CppFooContainer ()

    def __dealloc__(self):
       if self.thisptr:
           del self.thisptr
           self.thisptr = <CppFooContainer*> 0

    def __getitem__(self, int i):
       cdef CppFoo f  = deref(self.thisptr)[i]  #just one out of many try
```

I'm probably missing the trivial solution but I always end up with the error: "Cannot convert Python object to 'CppFoo'". Which is the proper way to use the operator[] ?

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer or not, but why do you have `cdef cppclass CppFoo "Foo"` and `cdef cppclass CppFooContainer "FooContainer"` instead of just `cdef cppclass CppFooContainer` and `cdef cppclass CppFooContainer`?

Comment: Oh, actually, I see now, `CppFoo` is actually `Foo` in the C++ header and you want to wrap it with a Python extension class also named `Foo`? You probably can't get away with reusing the name like that, but I'm not sure...the error looks like Cython thinks `Foo operator[](int)` returns a Python `Foo` rather than a `CppFoo` (a.k.a. `Foo` from C++)

Comment: Try changing `FooContainer()` to `CppFooContainer()` and `Foo operator[](int)` to `CppFoo operator[](int)` though, maybe?

Comment: Thanks @StephenLin, I made this error while trying to simplify my original problem. With this example now working I also found my mistake in the original problem (I forgot to dereference thisptr). I think that this question is probably useless, should I delete it ?

Comment: well, it's up to you? are you even allowed to delete it yourself, though? there's no harm leaving it I think.

Comment: then maybe you could turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it and "close" this question ?

Comment: sure, I assume what I wrote below correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of `operator[]` is correct (Cython does not require special syntax for the array indexing operator), but

```
cdef extern from "foo.h":
   cdef cppclass CppFooContainer "FooContainer":
     FooContainer()
     Foo operator[](int)
```

should be:

```
cdef extern from "foo.h":
   cdef cppclass CppFooContainer "FooContainer":
     CppFooContainer()
     CppFoo operator[](int)
```

since `FooContainer` and `Foo` refer to the Python extension class types declared afterwards rather than the C++ class types from "foo.h".